# Should I bind internal values when preparing queries in PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement

Having the following code

```
<?php
$age = get_age(); // a generated or random unsigned integer
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE name = :name AND age = :age");
$db->bindValue('name', $_POST['name']);
$db->bindValue('age',  $age, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$db->execute();
```

**Should I bind 'age' even if it doesn't come from the user (i.e outside)?**

If I have a fixed age or it's somehow generated by me, should I just do this?

```
<?php
$age = get_age(); // <- Of course I made sure this is an unsigned integer
$db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE name = :name AND age = $age");
$db->bindValue('name', $_POST['name']);
$db->execute();
```

Are there pros and cons for each or is it just personal preference?

Comment: If it is internal, it could have gotten there from external from some other attack vector. That is how a time bomb of 2nd level sql injection becomes 1st level with a boom. Just saying.

Comment: It's a good practice to bind any value from PHP and as possible never interpolate variable data into SQL directly. This prevents accidents on later code changes. Also, when preparing a statement, it is ready to multiple fast executions without overhead on each single one.

Comment: @Drew ok but what I'm just typing the age directly, I mean `AND age = 17`. Should I do that or better `AND age = :age` and then `bindValue('age', 17, PDO::PARAM_INT)` ?

Comment: Personally I wouldn't bind, but I am interested to learn "the other attack vector" stated by @Drew

Comment: Personally I always bind everything and then I never even have to think about SQL injection. Any time you don't bind you have to know *exactly* how that variable got there and anything besides hard-coding the value in your script right before the query and you're possibly going to have to follow a mental paper trail to make sure users can never touch it either directly or indirectly. Also worth mentioning is that prepared statements  make your queries reusable, so if you wanted to change it from `17` to `56` you don't have to resend the whole query again, just the values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I bind "internal" values when preparing queries in PDO?

Yes.

You should understand the difference between a silly artificial example and a mature real life code during its lifetime span.

If you want to learn how to write a mature code, consider the following:

- **there is a thing called a consistency.** Your first example looks consistent while second is not. After all, it's just a simple rule to follow - every variable should go into query via placeholder. Why hinder your development and puzzle yourself pondering on exceptions?
- **every application tends to grow and evolve**. The source of $age may be changed in the future.
- **not every code is just a spaghetti bowl with SQL queries run on the spot.** Some programmers being able to grasp the *separation of concerns* concept, making their application modular and flexible. In such an application, at the time of a query execution a database layer has absolutely no clue where the data is coming from, whether it's "safe" or not nor what does it "safe" mean at all.
- **all this binding hassle is not about "external" variables**. But just for the query integrity. Whatever "internal" value could just have incorrect format to be placed in the query directly. Imagine your function fails and returns an empty string. It will result in an SQL error in the second case. **You have to understand that you are binding your values [not for Bobby Tables but for Sarah O'Hara](https://phpdelusions.net/sql_injection#whatis).**

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need to bind in your context due to the usage parametter in your sql statement (see: http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.bindvalue.php).

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<?php
$age = get_age(); // <- Of course I made sure this is an unsigned integer
$sth= $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM Customers WHERE name = ? AND age = ?");
$values = array("john", $age);
$sth->execute($values);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a personal preference, in this case. And I think this is better for understanding the query when this is a big query. But, if a day someone change the function get_age() to retrieve the data by user, this could be dangerous.